# Initial value of a signal Simulink

Tags: matlab, real-time, simulink

I am working on a yacht velocity prediction program (VPP) in Simulink (I can't upload the image as I am a new user to this forum, apparently).

Solving the problem requires me to know the apparent wind speed and angle (VA and beta, respectively) in order to obtain the force generated by the sails and hence the net force, acceleration and ultimately speed of the boat. However, VA depends on the boat speed (VS). I tried putting in the initial value of the latter through the integrator block which converts the acceleration into speed but I keep getting the following error inside the "Apparent wind" m-function: "Index expression out of bounds. Attempted to access element 3. The valid range is 1-1.". Note that if I rearrange the model and feed the function with a constant value, say, it will work (although the resultant boat speed will not be physically correct). Listing of the m-function is shown below.

Simplified block diagram:

[VT,gamma] -> Apparent wind -> aero- & hydrodynamics -> force/mass -> acceleration -> 1/s -> VS

```
function [VA, beta] = fcn(inputs)
% 1 - gamma  % true wind heading [deg]
% 2 - VT  % true wind speed [kts]
% 3 - VS

%#codegen

% apparent wind angle [deg]
beta=atan(sin(inputs(1)*pi/180)/(cos(inputs(1)*pi/180)+inputs(3)/inputs(2)))/pi*180;    

% apparent wind speed [kts]
VA=sin(inputs(1)*pi/180)/sin(beta*pi/180)*inputs(2);    

end
```

EDIT: Please find the attached flowchart of the model now that I can actually upload one.

[image]

Comment: These formulas seem simple enough that an embedded matlab function block is overkill. It seems like it would be more appropriate to just implement the formulas for beta and VA using simulink math operation blocks.

Comment: I've done this already and it works. But I would still like to know what I am doing wrong not to repeat that in the future :)

Comment: In your MATLAB function, where is the variable `VS` coming from (as used in the equation `beta=atan(sin(inputs(1)*pi/180)/(cos(inputs(1)*pi/180)+VS/inputs(2)))/pi*180; `)?

Comment: I think that now that your rep is above 10, you might be able to post an image of your model.

Comment: I have added the flow chart as you suggested grungetta. As you can see, the VS is fed back to the apparent wind function and uses an initial condition IC_VS=10 knots (rough guess of the boat speed for the current sailing state).

Comment: I'm still unclear on how VS is actually being set in your code, though.  You create a bus using gamma, VT, and VS then feed this into your MATLAB function as `input`. So input should be a 3 element array (just as a side note you could achieve the same results using a Mux rather than a Bus Creator block).  In order to access the signal VS, you would need to do something like `VS=input(3);`.  Because you don't do this, I'm unclear on how the variable `VS` in your code (not the signal VS in your model) is actually being assigned (if it is at all).

Comment: Also, you do not actually need to use an IC (Initial Condition) block to set the initial condition for the Integrator. The IC block is used to set the initial condition of the signal that passes through it. So in this case, at the first time step, the value that is output from IC_VS is 10.  At every subsequent timestep, this signal is simply connected to ground. So essentially you are setting the initial condition of the initial condition input to the Integrator. It would suffice to simply have a constant block with a value of 10 connected to the initial condition input of the Integrator.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the initial condition for me. I wan't sure how to use it so I simply copied the layout of one of the models I found online when looking for some answers.

You were right about the fact that in the listing I posted there was an error. I was referring to VS as "VS" rather than "input(3)" although it was correct the first time I encountered the problem (I must have changed it when I was trying to work out what was wrong).

At the moment I think that for some reason Simulink treats my input signal not as a vector but a singular variable for some reason.

Comment: Could you be more clear as to whether it is now solved or that you are still struggeling?

Comment: Did you try setting the initial condition directly in the integrator block?

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

Why is signal dimension not propagated properly when Embedded MATLAB blocks are used in a closed loop at
http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-9TQFRN/?product=SL&solution=1-9TQFRN

Good luck.

GM

Comment: just providing link won't help .He is facing prob.